# Most probable value for the successor (in ascending order) of a known statistical unit

Tags: normal-distribution, sampling, conditional-expectation, order-statistics

Let $n$ be an integer $>1$.
Suppose a sample $(x_{k})_{k\in[[ 1;n]]}$ is taken from a known distribution on $\mathbb{R}$.
Given $x_1$ and supposing $\exists k\in[[2,n]], x_k>x_1$, what is the most likely minimum of $\{x_k \mid k\in [[ 1;n]] \land x_k>x_1\}$ ?
The default question implies no particular order on $(x_k)$ but I would also be interested in answers when one supposes that $\forall(k_1,k_2)\in[[1;n]]^2,k_1>k_2\implies x_{k_1}>x_{k_2}$.

Comment: Are the samples independent?

Comment: @jbowman they are indeed.

Comment: Since the distribution is known, evidently the most likely value *for each unobserved data point* is the one which maximizes $f(x)$, e.g., in the case of a Normal distribution, the mean.

Comment: @jbowman I was thinking of the x_k immediately following x_i in the sense that x_k > x_i, not k > i

Comment: Maybe it would be clearer to ask: Suppose a sample $S=x_1, \ldots x_n$ is chosen from a distribution. Given $x_1$, what is your best estimate for the minimum of $\{s\in S:s>x_1\}$?

Comment: (1) *How* do you come to know the value of one of the observations? (2) Do you also know the rank of $x_i$ among these $n$ values or not? (3) In what sense to you mean "best"?  What are your loss function and other estimation criteria (e.g., unbiased, minimax, *etc.*)?

Comment: @whuber (1) by hypothesis (for example suppose I got it by reading tabular microdata where all other cells were masked) (2) I would be interested by the answer in each of these cases (3) by best I mean the most probable value

Comment: @MattF. You are totally right, I will edit the post accordingly

Comment: Please edit your post to include those clarifications.  Your answer to (1) raises additional concerns, because the answer will depend on *why* all the other cells were masked.  For instance, maybe they were masked because they were all to large or too small, a process that in itself yields important information about the probabilities.

Comment: @whuber I edited the question. Other cells were masked totally at random (or to be clearer exactly one cell was revealed at random, not because its particular value)

Comment: When $x_1$ is the largest value in the sample (which has at least a $1/n$ chance of occurring) then by definition the minimum of the sample values exceeding $x_1$ is $\infty$ (the minimum of any empty set of real numbers).  That would make $\infty$ the expected value as well as the most likely value.  How do you propose to cope with this?

Comment: @whuber you are perfectly right, thanks. The question makes little sense if we let open the possibility that x1 is the maximum of the sample. I edited the post accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

We use $x_{(i)}$ to denote the $i^{th}$ smallest of the $x$'s, as is standard in order statistics. We use $F$ and $f$ for the cdf and pdf of $X$.

We can start from the Beta distribution for uniform order statistics: for $n$ uniform variables $u_i$ in $[0,1]$, $u_{(i)}\sim B(i,n+1-i)$ and $Eu_{(i)}=i/(n+1)$.

Since the cdf's of $X$ have a uniform distribution, this implies:

$$EF(x_{(i)})=\frac{i}{n+1}$$
$$E\Big[F(x_{(i+1)})-F(x_{(i)})\Big]=\frac1{n+1}$$

So as a first approximation for the question, we can use

$$x_{(i+1)} \simeq F^{-1}\Big(F(x_i)+\frac{1}{n+1}\Big),$$
which for large $n$ gives approximately
$$x_{(i+1)} \simeq x_i+\frac{1}{(n+1)f(x_i)}.$$

A more refined answer would still have a similar order of magnitude. For a normal distribution, this has $e^{x^2/2\sigma^2}$ in the numerator, and means that you can't predict the next ordered $x$ with much accuracy.

Comment: When $k=n,$ this proposal would have us draw an inference about a nonexistent $x_{(n+1)}$!

Comment: Thanks. Do you have any formal proof that this approximation holds? I do not see what you mean by $E[F(x_{(i+1)})-F(x_{(i)})]$